# Label crops when open new view and back to home controller

Tags: ios, uiview

Label crops when I open a new view and then return back to the home controller. How can I solve this issue?

[image]

1. Red colour label cuts when I open new view and back again to Homeview. It looks like this.
2. That view must look like 2nd Image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put constraint on view. You need to enable width and height constraint on this button.
Here is the constraint window [you need to set width and height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1wXq.png)